# Selecting rows in Pandas Panel

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to select rows from across a Pandas panel?

For instance in the following example could I get all rows where Job == "B" across dataframes? In a regular dataframe I know I could do this using

> df1[df1["job"] == "A"]

but I'm unsure how to do this in Pandas panels without loops.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"job":["A", "B", "C", "D"],"date":["DateA1", "DateB1", "DateC1", "DateD1"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"job":["B", "C", "D", "E"],"date":[ "DateB2", "DateC2", "DateD2", "DateE2"]})
p = pd.Panel({"df1":df1, "df2":df2})
```

My question might be a duplicate of this one

[Boolean Masking in Panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650341/boolean-mask-in-pandas-panel)

Answer (score 1):

It might be more convenient (at least to me :-)) to work with 2D df rather than 3D panel.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"job":["A", "B", "C", "D"],"date":["DateA1", "DateB1", "DateC1", "DateD1"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"job":["B", "C", "D", "E"],"date":[ "DateB2", "DateC2", "DateD2", "DateE2"]})
p = pd.Panel({"df1":df1, "df2":df2})

frame = p.to_frame()

Out[12]: 
                df1     df2
major minor                
0     date   DateA1  DateB2
      job         A       B
1     date   DateB1  DateC2
      job         B       C
2     date   DateC1  DateD2
      job         C       D
3     date   DateD1  DateE2
      job         D       E


res = frame.unstack('minor').stack(level=0)

Out[13]: 
minor        date job
major                
0     df1  DateA1   A
      df2  DateB2   B
1     df1  DateB1   B
      df2  DateC2   C
2     df1  DateC1   C
      df2  DateD2   D
3     df1  DateD1   D
      df2  DateE2   E


res.loc[res['job'] == 'B', :]

Out[14]: 
minor        date job
major                
0     df2  DateB2   B
1     df1  DateB1   B
```

Comment: Jianxun, I agree with you but I'm trying to force myself to learn about Panels as there HAS to be a reason they were implemented (or so I think?) This brings up the broader question for me which is why use Panels over a MultiIndex? I really don't know enough about Panels but I'm struggling to find the benefit. Any ideas?

Comment: @canyon289 I don't have so much experience with `Panel`. My personal preference of stacked `dataframe` over `Panel` is that stacked `dataframe` allows me to do interactive analysis by easily printing out intermediate results, while in `panel` you cannot visualize all components at the same time in your terminal because of its 3D nature.